# web app OO concept confusion

Tags: sql, ajax, oop, web-applications

This is a concept question, regarding "best practice" and "efficient use" of resources.
Specifically dealing with large data sets in a db and on-line web applications, and moving from a procedural processing approach to a more Object Oriented approach.

Take a "list" page, found in almost all CRUD aspects of the application. The list displays a company, address and contact. For the sake of argument, and "proper" RDBM, assume we've normalized the data such that a company can have multiple addresses, and contacts.
- for our scenario, lets say I have a list of 200 companies, each with 2-10 addresses, each address has a contact. i.e. any franchise where the 'store' is named 'McDonalds', but there may be multiple addresses by that 'name').

TABLES

- companies
- addresses
- contacts

To this point, I'd make a single DB call and use joins to pull back ALL my data, loop over the data and output each line... Some grouping would be done at the application layer to display things in a friendly manner. (this seems like the most efficient way, as the RDBM did the heavy lifting - there was a minimum network calls (one to the db, one from the db, one http request, one http response).

Another way of doing this, if you couldn't group at the application layer, is to query for the company list, loop over that, and inside the loop make separate DB call(s) for the address, contact. less efficient, because you're making multiple DB calls

Now - the question, or sticking point.... Conceptually...

If I have a company object, an address object and a contact object - it seems that in order to achieve the same result - you would call a 'getCompanies' method that would return a list, and you'd loop over the list, and call 'getAdderss' for each, and likewise a 'getContact' - passing in the company ID etc.

In a web app - this means A LOT more traffic from the application layer to the DB for the data, and a lot of smaller DB calls, etc. - it seems SERIOUSLY less effective.

If you then move a fair amount of this logic to the client side, for an AJAX application, you're incurring network traffic ON TOP of the increased internal network overhead.

Can someone please comment on the best ways to approach this. Maybe its a conceptual thing.

Someone suggested that a 'gateway' is when you access these large data-sets, as opposed to smaller more granular object data - but this doesn't really help my understanding,and Im not sure it's accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Of course getting everything you need at once from the database is the most efficient. You don't need to give that up just because you want to write your code as an OO model. Basically, you get all the results from the database first, then translate the tabular data into a hierarchical form to fill objects with. "getCompanies" could make a single database call joining addresses and contacts, and return "company" objects that contain populated lists of "addresses" and "contacts". See [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Comment: yes, i could have an object return ALL the joined data and that doesn't break the 'object' - however (conceptually), returning all this data that pertains to "company" means I'm returning a lot of data that MAY be useless based on what I'm doing programatically.

for instance, an AUTOCOMPLETE query should really only retrun the company name and ID, there is no "need" for the address fields and the contact fields, for that matter the joins. so "getCompany()" - returning all VS. getCompany(id). r u saying two different 'gets' like getCompanyDetails, or getCompanyList? a method for every set??

Comment: that seems like an awful lot of special objects OR methods that take an inordinate about of arguments. Just curious if this is common - and something that just needs to be defined and decided in every app...

Comment: @jpmyob Yes, the system should be flexible enough to let you choose what you want to join. You wouldn't need a different type of object for each type of join though, because the "getAddresses()" method of a "company" object could simply return nothing if the address table wasn't joined (or it could query the database on the first call and use the cached result from then on -- this is called lazy loading).

Comment: @jpmyob With a good object-relational mapper, there is usually no need for defining specialized functions like "getCompanies", "getCompaniesWithAddresses", etc. For example, using SQLAlchemy (an ORM for Python) as an example, you could get companies and their addresses (but not contacts) with this code: `session.query(Company).join(Address)` The `query` and `join` functions are defined in the library already, and you only need to define the `Company` and `Address` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with exactly this issue many times. The first and MOST important thing to remember is : don't optimize prematurely. Optimize your code for readability, the DRY principle, etc., then come back and fix things that are "slow".

However, specific to this case, rather than iteratively getting the addresses for each company one at a time, pass a list of all the company IDs to the fetcher, and get all the addresses for all those company ids, then cache that list of addresses in a map. When you need to fetch an address by addressID, fetch it from that local cache. This is called an IdentityMap. However, like I said, I don't recommend recoding the flow for this optimization until needed. Most often there are 10 things on a page, not 100 so you are saving only a few milliseconds by changing the "normal" flow for the optimized flow.

Of course, once you've done this 20 times, writing code in the "optimized flow" becomes more natural, but you also have the experience of when to do it and when not to.